# Read out list of objects in Java

Tags: java, object

Hi i'm trying to read out the following object:

[image]

Can anyone help me out how I need the value for the project?

I already tried this:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < ((Object[]) ret).length; i++){
                Map<String, Object> map2 = (Map<String, Object>) ret[i];
                int x = 0;
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map2.entrySet())
                {
                    //store data in list
                    if(x == 0){
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
                        x++;
                    }
                    if(x==1){
                      //read out projectid

                    }
                }
            }
```

When I try to output the value I got : project_id/[Ljava.lang.Object;@41923200

EDITED :

Showing data in listview :

```
private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            connector=new OpenerpRpc(getBaseContext());
            connector.Config();
            current_page += 1;
            listOffValues = getListOffFieldValues(current_page, false, listOffValues); 

            String[] from = { "project_id"};

            int[] to = { R.id.tv_project_id};
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), listOffValues, R.layout.lv_gps_layout, from, to);
            return adapter;
        }
        /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final SimpleAdapter adapter) {
            // Setting adapter for the listview
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){

                HashMap<String, Object[]> hm = (HashMap<String, Object[]>) adapter.getItem(i);
                    String projectID = (String) hm.get("project_id")[1].toString();

                HashMap<String, String> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmDownload.put("project_id",projectID);


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                        String listName;
                        HashMap<String, String> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        listName = hmDownload.get("project_id");
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YardActivity.class);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });

            }
            progress.dismiss();
            Log.d("/****","Data from odoo is finished");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with that output?

Comment: Have a look to my image, I would like to output the value Projects / Project NL / ....

Comment: Are you meaning to say that you want to display the PATH for the object as the output? Your question is confusing.

Comment: I want to get the value out of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confuse with your generic types and what `ret` is.

I think your problem is that values in your map are not objects, but arrays of objects - `Map<String, Object[]>`. Printing the array yields results such as `"[Ljava.lang.Object;@41923200"`, because arrays do not have `toString()` method.

You should do e.g. `hm.get("project_id")[1]` instead (assuming that `hm` is defined as `Map<String, Object[]>` and not as `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Yes indeed, but later on I would like to put that in this:   HashMap<String, Object[]> hm = (HashMap<String, Object[]>) adapter.getItem(i);
                    String projectID = (String) hm.get("project_id")[1].toString();
                hm.put("project_id",projectID); But by some reasen I can not use that with Object[].

Comment: You want to put `String` into array whose elements are `Object[]`? Why do you want to have a map with two different types of values at all?

Comment: I need that to in an other function. Now I would like to use that project_id in a listview, thats why im using a hasmap now at the moment.

Comment: I didn't ask why you are using hashmap. I asked why do you want to store two distinct types of values in a single map, instead of just using two maps - one for strings and one for arrays of objects?

Comment: I updated my code for my listview, so you can have a look. I have now data in my listview but still showing me java:lsddklfjd etc. But i'm getting the values out the project_id now. Thanks for that. But I can't figure out why still shows me java:dslkfd etc

Comment: java.lang.object @438223c